# Implementing this kind of typography in LaTeX

Tags: typography

How can I get the following typography in LaTeX?

[image]

I tried:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{mathrsfs}

\begin{document}

$\mathscr{Typography}$

\end{document}
```

But it doesn't work.

Comment: Do you really want a font face for the first letter ("A") that's completely different from the font used for the remaining letters? Please advise.

Comment: I want to reproduce the same thing in the photo.

Comment: The mathrsfs package provides curly forms of capital letters, for use in some mathematical notation. It does not provide lower case. The letters themselves look nothing like those in your image. I think you want to switch to some sort of gothic text font (maybe [seagram](https://www.dafont.com/seagram-tfb.font)).

Comment: @Ian Thompson, yes

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Using `luatex`, you can easily access any font installed on your system. I suggest something like this (Seagram tfb isn't a perfect match, but you get the idea).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\newfontfamily\seagram{{Seagram tfb}}
\begin{document}
Agradecimientos

\seagram{Agradecimientos}
\end{document}
```

Compile this with `lualatex` to get the following.

[image]

Comment: +1 for not mixing math-mode and text-mode approaches

Answer (score 13):

The uppercase letter "A" might come from the "Euler" math-calligraphy font set. The remaining letters would appear to come from some text-mode Fraktur font face. I couldn't find a perfect match, but the output of `\textfrak` (provided by the `yfonts` package) comes fairly close.

[image]

A word of caution: It is entirely inappropriate, typographically and aesthetically speaking, to use math mode to bring about font changes in text-mode material. Moreover, I cannot get my head around why anyone would want to mix-and-mismatch calligraphic and fraktur font faces in one and the same word. Casting a glance at the screenshot posted above, I can only shudder and avert my eyes...

```
\documentclass{article} 
\usepackage[cal=euler]{mathalpha} % "Euler" calligraphic 
\usepackage{yfonts} % for '\textfrak' macro

\begin{document}
$\mathcal{A}$\textfrak{gradecimientos:}
\end{document}
```

Comment: @Fractal - If you absolutely, positively have to reproduce the screenshot you posted, try running `\usepackage[cal=euler,frak=euler]{mathalpha}` in the preamble and typing `$\mathcal{A}\mathfrak{gradecimientos}$` in the body of the LaTeX document. :-)

Answer (score 2):

Mico's answer explains how to typeset the example. I'd like to add a version of this solution with Euclid Fraktur fonts which seem to be the ones used in the example brought by the topic starter (checked with [Font Finder](https://www.whatfontis.com/)).

Euclid Fraktur font family was developed by Design Science (now Wiris) for their MathType product and is currently available from many Font libraries on the Web. It is not clear what the license is, so may require additional research before downloading the fonts, depending on your local legislation.

Processing the following with `lualatex`

```latex
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\fontspec[
   Path      = /opt/fonts/EuclidFraktur-Regular/,
   Extension = .ttf,
   Ligatures = TeX,
]{EuclidFraktur-Regular}
\newfontfamily{\euclid}{EuclidFraktur-Regular}
\usepackage[cal=euler]{mathalpha}
\begin{document}

$\mathcal{A}\textrm{\euclid{gradecimientos}}$
\end{document}
```

would produce a PDF file that looks like this:
[image: Agradecimientos]

Comment: I still think you need to run something like `\usepackage[cal=euler]{mathalpha}` in order to get the initial letter to conform to the OP's screeshot.

Comment: @Mico you are correct. I missed the difference. Will try to get mathalpha installed and update the post.